# Can I customize rate limiting in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, lumen, rate-limiting

Is there any way through which the rate limit duration can be customized?

For instance, I am using the default Laravel rate limiter.
I would want to have something like - *allow 10 requests per hour*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Laravel throttle](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Throttle)** is a rate limiter for the Laravel application.

You can make your request safe implementing laravel throttle by route group like :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'throttle:10,60'], function () {
  Route::get('your_route', 'YourController@your_method');
  Route::post('your_route2', 'YourController@your_method2');
});
```

or

```
Route::middleware('throttle:10,60')->group(function () {
  Route::get('/user', function () {
    //
  });
});
```

Here **10** requests allowed in every **60 minutes** *(1 hour)* by a single user or session IP. You have to test it on a live server. It would not work in localhost.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am just curious is it not possible by tweaking the default rate limiter which laravel provides?

Comment: Laravel uses the same rate limiter dy default that I mentioned, 
Here is the datails https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Throttle

Comment: "It would not work in localhost" whys that?

Comment: @Flame cause the IP