# Can I limit number of requests based on route?

Tags: laravel, api, backend

I have api key and send requests to other service and I want to limit number of requests. Could I restrict number of requests on the specific route in laravel, but restrict all the users despite their's ip?

Comment: Yes, you can https://stackoverflow.com/a/65479451/4575350

Comment: limit number of requests for who? everyone?  requests coming in? requests to other services?

Comment: Requests come from users who use app, I want to limit number of requests from my server to external api, for instance, google or facebook

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using? there is a RateLimiter in the framework you could use

Comment: I use Laravel 8.11.2 version

Comment: Laravel 8 comes with a RateLimiter ... https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#rate-limiting even though that is in the Queue section you can use that any where (anything related to middleware or queue can be ignored in that section as it doesn't apply to what you are doing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of search, I found answer in [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#rate-limiting) .

You can limit number of requests per route like that

```
RateLimiter::for('uploads', function (Request $request) {
    return Limit::perMinute(1000)->response(function () {
        return response('Custom response...', 429);
    });
});


Route::middleware(['throttle:uploads'])->group(function () {
  Route::post('/audio', function () {
  
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use laravel throttle middleware

for laravel 5,6,7 use this

```
Route::post('api/api-key','ApiController@getKey')->middleware('throttle:60,1');
```

for Laravel 8

```
Route::post('api/api-key',[ApiController::class,'getKey'])->middleware('throttle:60,1');
```

for more throttle for api-key read this [article](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/laravel-and-api-rate-limiting/)

Comment: Isn't throttle based on user ip which request has?

Comment: I need to restrict all requests based on route, not ip.
So If "/token" - there should be only 100 requests per hour from any ip.