# Lock out user for given amount of time

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have the following custom login controller;

But I want to lock the user out for an hour, at the moment it just locks them out for about 60 seconds or so, is this possible?

```php
public function login(Request $request)
{
     if (RateLimiter::tooManyAttempts(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip(), 5)) {
          return response()->json([
               'message' => 'Account locked for an hour'
          ]);
     }

     $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

     if (! Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
          RateLimiter::hit(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip());

          return response()->json([
               'status_code' => 401,
               'message' => 'Unauthorized',
          ]);
     } else {

          RateLimiter::clear(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip());

          return response()->json([
               'status_code' => 200,
               'message' => 'Welcome',
          ]);
     }
}
```

Comment: Using `?:` instead of `||` is peculiar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I customize rate limiting in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65479243/can-i-customize-rate-limiting-in-laravel)

Comment: There is `decay` option that you can use for counting down till the moment an user can login again

Comment: @tadman .. No it needs to be custom due to some other processing that i am doiing

Comment: @HuyPhạm .. This is on the hit method right? But if it hits twice then it doest work

Comment: Throttle is a middleware to limit HTTP requests. Which is good for a lot of things but if you're trying to limit input based on some amount of time but not limit overall requests by a user to a page then it won't do.

Answer (score 1):

The [rate limiting documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/rate-limiting) seems very centered around the idea of a specific number of requests allowed per minute.

Digging into the [API articles for RateLimiter](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Cache/RateLimiter.html) there is a `$decaySeconds` parameter after the which can be specified on the  `attempt()` and `hit()` functions. This value comes in after the parameter you are using as your identification key to rate limit. In your case `$credentials`

So you should be able to do something like this...

```
//Forth parameter of attempt is how long until the attempt 'decays' from the system.
if (! Auth::attempt($credentials, 5, null, 3600)) {
          RateLimiter::hit(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip());

          return response()->json([
               'status_code' => 401,
               'message' => 'Unauthorized',
          ]);
}
```

Notably the rate limiter just appears to a pre-configured set of functions using the [Cache API in Laravel.](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cache)

So alternatively you could build your own rate limited methodology as well by using `Cache::put()` and `Cache::has()` methods with custom logic and expiry times that are tailored to whatever you're trying to limit.

Comment: thank you for getting back to me ... There used to be a global variable that could be put in the controller, is that still around? .. Writing something for the Cache is way over my head

Answer (score 0):

You can set timeout in seconds in Authcontroller where default timeout is 60 seconds.

=> Step to implement custom locking time functionality in Laravel :

```
1. Go to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php.

2. protected $maxLoginAttempts = 10; // Amount of bad attempts user can make
protected $lockoutTime = 300; // Time for which user is going to be blocked in seconds
```

With help of these variables, you can do whatever you need.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/31F6D.png

Comment: I believe this is only availbale if you use the laravel/ui package and the default authentication functinoality

Comment: Yes because if we use the default package given by Laravel then it is a very easy and time-saving process for what we want to achieve in fast pace development process.